# Core Data Migration addAuthorsObject

Tags: ios, core-data-migration

I've read an article about Core Data Migration from here: http://www.objc.io/issue-4/core-data-migration.html. I don't understand the following line:

```
[destinationInstance performSelector:@selector(addAuthorsObject:) withObject:author];
```

destinationInstance is a book NSManagedObject, author is an author NSManagedObject. They are related(a book can have multiple authors, and an author can write multiple books.). The code above should be establishing this relationship. But where is this addAuthorsObject: being declared? How can I add a relationship NSManagedObject to another NSManagedObject in my own project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you post is identical to `[destinationInstance addAuthorsObject:author]`; `addAuthorsObject:` is a method automatically added to your `NSManagedObject` subclass by Core Data at runtime, because you've declared that the object has a to-many relationship called `authors`.

So `addAuthorsObject:` isn't declared; it's created when the schema is loaded. You can't look at it because it's not actually written anywhere.

Xcode has a graphical editor for Core Data schemas; you should use it to add extra objects, properties and relationships. You'll then probably want to create custom subclasses for your model objects but it's not actually required.

Comment: Brilliant! That's what I thought honestly. But I've made a silly mistake. I forgot to add to-many relationship (the default is to-one) and Xcode threw an exception when I called this runtime add--Object: method. Thank you, mate.